# how to enable vertical scroll in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, scroll, datatables

I need to be able to scroll **table** element using a jquery mobile.

For example now I have a lot of data in the table. 
and my page shows me  20 records and I know that there are 25 records so when I want to scroll vertically my whole page is moving and not my table as it should.

I am using DataTables plugin for the table.

Code:

```
<table id="level" width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5" >
                <thead>
                    <tr class="even">
                        <th></th>
                        <th><span class="time_var">Time</span></th>
                        <th><span class="id_level_var">ID Level</span></th>
                        <th><span class="level_var">Level</span></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

              <tbody>
              </tbody>
        </table>
```

And javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        oTable = $('#level').dataTable( {
            "bLengthChange": false,
                    "aaSorting": [[1,'asc']],
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "sScrollY": "500px",
            "bDeferRender": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "table.php"
        } );
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried :

```
<div style="width:260px; overflow:scroll" >
   //your dataTable
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing a

```
} );
```

to catch your document.ready?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    oTable = $('#level').dataTable( {
        "bLengthChange": false,
                "aaSorting": [[1,'asc']],
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sScrollY": "500px",
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "table.php"
    } );
});
```

Your code is working here:
http://live.datatables.net/otihog/edit#javascript,html